# Функции С++, возвращающие и нет

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Здравствуйте.

Появился вопрос чисто "технического" плана.

Вот объявил я функцию

```
int Function(char* a, char* b, int c)
{
c = strlen(a)+strlen(b);
return 0;
}
```

теперь в главной функции

```
char* a = new char[10]; cin>>a;
char* b = new char[10]; cin>>b;
int c;

Function(a, b, c);
cout<<c;
```

Выводит 0...

А если сделать так:

```
 int Function(char* a, char* b)
    {
    c = strlen(a)+strlen(b);
    return с;
    }
```

теперь в главной функции

```
char* a = new char[10]; cin>>a;
char* b = new char[10]; cin>>b;
int c;

с = Function(a, b);
cout<<c;
```

Все работает.

Вопрос, в каком случае можно использовать первый вариант и почему он не работает в таком виде? (Я успел заметить что у функций потока, как раз таки первый вариант используется, а у меня работать не хочет)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

С параметрами функций нужно понять вот это:

1. реально ты ничего в функцию не
       передаёшь (саму переменную)
2. на деле ты создаёшь в функции новую
       переменную и одновременно
       присваиваешь ей значение

допустим у нас есть

```
int Function(char* Va, char &Vb, int Vc) //создаём указатель, ссылку, и переменную
{
 Vc = strlen(Va)+strlen(Vb);
 return 0;
}
```

в главной

```
//у нас есть *a,*b,c
Function(a,b,c);//на этой строчке происходит вот что:
/* внутри Function, это происходит после "Function(" но до "){" */
char Va=a;
char Vb=&b; //так как слева ссылка то автоматически подставляется имперсанд
int Vc=c;
```

внутренности скобок (у Function) нужно рассматривать не как передачу a-b-c , а как создание новых переменных со значениями a-b-c;

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно, что надо делать с ссылкой в первом варианте)

Answer (score 4):

[@BlackOverlord](/users/5101/blackoverlord), а лучше в первом варианте явно передать указатель на `c`.

```
int Function(char* a, char* b, int *c)
{
    *c = strlen(a)+strlen(b);
    return 0;
}

main () {
    ....
    int c;
    Function(a, b, &c);
    cout<<c;
}
```

Всем сразу (при просмотре кода) становится ясно, что задумал автор.

Ведь в случае передачи по ссылке, без просмотра кода (или прототипа Function), в main совершенно не понятно, что Function изменит `a`.

В конце концов, ведь Вы совершенно не ожидаете, что при вызове

```
a = strlen(str);
```

`str` изменится?

Comment: Это точно!

Comment: Это не полный исходник, я его урезал до самого минимума, что бы здесь разместить, ведь не удобно копаться в  большом объеме, да и больше ни к чему было постить)

Comment: Тем более. 

А теперь представьте, что код функции в отдельном .cpp, а ее прототип во включаемом .h и все это чужой код, в которм Вы ищете логическую ошибку. 

Это я по поводу ссылок и указателей.

Answer (score 1):

> в каком случае можно использовать первый вариант и почему он не работает в таком виде?

Первый вариант нужно использовать при передаче параметра `c` **по ссылке**. Ну, и не работает, соответственно потому что, `c` передается **по значению**, т.е. `c` модифицируется в функции локально (см. ["Передача параметра"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Параметр_(программирование)#.D0.9F.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.B0_.D0.BF.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0))!